# What is the correct way of create a get request for retrieve a tickets in zendesk

Tags: ajax, api, zendesk-api

if my username is name123@test.com and API token is 123456789 then how to create a get request for retrieving tickets related to the user

I tried this way and got always unauthorized as response

```
                $.ajax({
                 url: 'https://mysubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json',
                 beforeSend: function (request) {
                     request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic 
                    name123@test.com;123456789"); 
                     request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                 },

        success: function (data) { 
            console.log( data);
                 },
       error: function (err) {
             console.log(err);
                 }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/introduction/#api-token), the proper format for using tokens is `{email_address}/token:{api_token}`, as in `jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv`.  So looks like you need to add `/token` and the `;` semicolon should be replaced with a `:` colon.